# Select column value = 0 when packageid is null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to select 0 in packageid if the testid != packageid,
This is the select statement and example:

```
select distinct Order_Details_Cash.TESTID as 'Test ID' , 
       testname  as 'Test Name'  , 
       dept_name as 'Section Name' ,
       departments.Dept_id as 'dept id',
       sample_kind.Desc_Sample_kind as 'Sample Kind',
       Lab_Packages.packageid as 'package id'    
FROM Order_Details_Cash
inner join LabTests on Order_Details_cash.TESTID = LabTests.TestId
inner join Sample_Kind on LabTests.ID_sample = sample_kind.ID_sample
inner join Departments on LabTests.Dept_id = Departments.Dept_id
inner join Lab_orders_Cash on Lab_orders_Cash.cash_order_id = Order_Details_Cash.CASH_ORDER_ID
left join Lab_Packages on Order_Details_Cash.TESTID = Lab_Packages.packageid
where CONVERT(varchar,[Order_Details_Cash].CASH_ORDER_ID) = 2000000805
and Lab_orders_Cash.order_status = 1
```

And the output for this select:

```
Test ID    Test Name                 Section Name        dept id    Sample Kind package id
  5        IRON                      Clinical Chemistry  2          Serum        NULL
  7        FERRITIN                  Hormones            4          Serum        NULL
 7314      General Check Up package  Hematology          1          Serum        7314
```

How to select packageid = 0 for tests id  5 and 7 which is normal tests and not package from left join I select the packageid:

```
left join Lab_Packages on Order_Details_Cash.TESTID = Lab_Packages.packageid
```

and I need to select packageid=0 when testid not in Lab_Packages.packageid

```
Order_Details_Cash.TESTID != Lab_Packages.packageid
```

And I need the output for this select to be:

```
Test ID    Test Name                 Section Name        dept id    Sample Kind package id
  5        IRON                      Clinical Chemistry  2          Serum        0
  7        FERRITIN                  Hormones            4          Serum        0
 7314      General Check Up package  Hematology          1          Serum        7314
```

Comment: `COALESCE(Lab_Packages.packageid,0)`?

Comment: @DaleK thank you its working as I need , I put it in select   COALESCE(Lab_Packages.packageid,0) as 'package id' answer the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As DaleK said use

Coalesce(Lab_Packages.packageid,0) as 'package id'
Coalesce function will replace null value with the value you put which is 0 in my case.

this is the correct answer:

```
select distinct Order_Details_Cash.TESTID as 'Test ID' , 
       testname  as 'Test Name'  , 
       dept_name as 'Section Name' ,
       departments.Dept_id as 'dept id',
       sample_kind.Desc_Sample_kind as 'Sample Kind',
       Coalesce(Lab_Packages.packageid,0)as 'package id'  
FROM Order_Details_Cash
inner join LabTests on Order_Details_cash.TESTID = LabTests.TestId
inner join Sample_Kind on LabTests.ID_sample = sample_kind.ID_sample
inner join Departments on LabTests.Dept_id = Departments.Dept_id
inner join Lab_orders_Cash on Lab_orders_Cash.cash_order_id = Order_Details_Cash.CASH_ORDER_ID
left join Lab_Packages on Order_Details_Cash.TESTID = Lab_Packages.packageid
where CONVERT(varchar,[Order_Details_Cash].CASH_ORDER_ID) = 2000000805
and Lab_orders_Cash.order_status = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make the last field 0 if it's null.
Coalesce(Lab_Packages.packageid,0)as 'package id'

```
  select distinct Order_Details_Cash.TESTID as 'Test ID' , 
     testname  as 'Test Name'  , 
     dept_name as 'Section Name' ,
     departments.Dept_id as 'dept id',
     sample_kind.Desc_Sample_kind as 'Sample Kind',
     Coalesce(Lab_Packages.packageid,0)as 'package id'     
FROM Order_Details_Cash
inner join LabTests on Order_Details_cash.TESTID = LabTests.TestId
inner join Sample_Kind on LabTests.ID_sample = sample_kind.ID_sample
inner join Departments on LabTests.Dept_id = Departments.Dept_id
inner join Lab_orders_Cash on Lab_orders_Cash.cash_order_id = 
Order_Details_Cash.CASH_ORDER_ID
left join Lab_Packages on Order_Details_Cash.TESTID = Lab_Packages.packageid
where CONVERT(varchar,[Order_Details_Cash].CASH_ORDER_ID) = 2000000805
and Lab_orders_Cash.order_status = 1
```